# TOR browser - -ExcludeNodes doesn't work

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, relays, exit-relays, node

Using Linux, at *torrc*.

Format used: *(at end file)*

```
ExcludeNodes {...},{...},{...},{...}

ExcludeExitNodes {...},{...},{...},{...}
```

Continues connecting to excluded country nodes.

Know how to fix?